# Java Generics - is this unchecked cast safe?

Tags: java, generics, casting, warnings

I have (another) unchecked cast question.  I am 90% sure that it is safe, but I want to make sure (I'm justifying the use of `@SupressWarnings` to another developer who is reviewing the code)

The following pattern has been set up by our framework:

```
abstract class Writer<T> {
    Class<T> valueType;

    Writer(Class<T> valueType) {
        this.valueType = valueType;
    }
}
class Cat { }

class CatWriter extends Writer<Cat> {
    CatWriter() {
        super(Cat.class);
    }
}
```

I am also using a subclass of `Writer` to write a class that makes use of generics:

```
class Color {}
class Green extends Color {}
class Brown extends Color {}
```

My writer class looks like this:

```
abstract class Bird<C extends Color> {}
class Parrot extends Bird<Green>{}
class Ostrich extends Bird<Brown>{}

class BirdWriter<C extends Color> extends Writer<Bird<C>> {
    BirdWriter(Bird<C> bird) {
        super((Class<Bird<C>>)bird.getClass());
    }
}
```

I could use raw types in the writer but that gives many more warnings. Instead I include the generics in the Writer class. This is fine everywhere but the constructor. I am forced to cast the `bird.getClass()` (which is a class object which has no generic signature) to a Class object *with* a generic signature. **This produces an *unchecked cast* warning on the cast,** but I believe it is safe to cast the result to `Class<Bird<C>>` because the `bird` that is passed into the parameter is guaranteed to be a `Bird<C>`.

Testing backs up my theory, but I want to make sure that my thinking is correct.  **Is there any way in which this code is unsafe?**

---

### Update

Thanks for your answers.  Because of the answers I realized there was a weakness in my structure and have revised it.

Essentially `Cat` uses a simple `Writer` that knows it's always writing a `Cat`.  In my case, I've got a type of "SmartAnimal" that can be written by a dynamic Writer, so that I don't have to create a `Writer` for every Animal.

```
class SmartAnimal {}
class Dog extends SmartAnimal {}
class Horse extends SmartAnimal {}
class SuperHorse extends Horse {}

class DynamicWriter<A extends SmartAnimal> extends Writer<A> {
    DynamicWriter(A smartAnimal) {
        super((Class<A>)smartAnimal.getClass());
    }
}
```

Again, I have the same warning, but this seems to be more safe.

**Is this better, and is it safe?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most certainly not correct, for the reason listed by ILMTitan [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810690/java-generics-is-this-unchecked-cast-safe/4810751#4810751).  But I'll give you a reason why it might also not be very safe.  Imagine you had a method `verifyType()` that made sure that anything that was passed in for writing was the correct type:

```
public void write(T t) {
   if (!verifyType(t)) explode();
   //...do write
}

public boolean verifyType(T t) {
   return valueType.isInstance(t);
}
```

This method you would expect never to fail, right?  After all, you're just ensuring that `t` is a `T` (since you have a `Class<T>`), and we already know it *is* a `T` because `write()` only accepts a `T`?  Right?  **Wrong!**  You're not actually checking if `t` is a `T`, but potentially some arbitrary subtype of `T`.

Examine what would happen if you declared a `Writer<Bird<Green>>` and instantiated it with a `Parrot<Green>`, it would be *legal* to do this call:

```
Writer<Bird<Green>> writer;
writer.write(new SomeOtherGreenBird());
```

And again you would not expect it to fail.  However your value type is for `Parrot` only, so the type check would fail.  It all depends what you're doing in your writer class, but be forewarned: you are treading in dangerous water here.  Declaring a `Class<? extends T>` in your writer would prevent you from making a mistake like this.

Comment: Thank you very much - this makes a lot of sense and exposed the weirdness with what I was doing.  I figured out the pattern a bit better, modified the use case and updated the question - can you answer the second question? Thanks again.

Comment: just after I posted that, I read your question again and implemented the code that you said would explode.  It still does.  But, I don't have any checks such as that in there, and write is purely polymorphic, so I should be fine - but at least I know how to explain this in the class comments.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You are not entirely correct. The correct, safe,  but still unchecked cast is to `Class<? extends Bird<C>>`, as the bird you are passed could, for instance, be an Owl, which would return a `Class<Owl>` which could be assigned to a `Class<? extends Bird<C>>`. Peter Lawrey is correct in the reason that this is unchecked but safe.

Update:

No, it is still not safe for the same reason. You can still do something like `new DynamicWriter<Horse>(new SuperHorse());` which would perform an unchecked cast from `Class<SuperHorse>` to `Class<Horse>`. To be safe, you need to cast to a `Class<? extends A>`.

Comment: Beat me to it.  A `Class<Owl<Green>>` is no more a `Class<Bird<Green>>` than a `List<String>` is a `List<Object>`.  It may be type safe, but that would require us knowing more about what `Writer` does with it.  If your `Writer` accepted `Class<? extends Bird<C>>` it would at least be more correct.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, its safe., The problem is that getClass() returns the class of the object at runtime, but the compiler doesn't understand what getClass() does, nor is there a syntax which does something like

```
Class<this> getClass();
```

possibly because its the only example of when it would be used.